# adicionar/remover array a um input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando um código jQuery para adicionar produtos que são escolhidos em um *select list* à uma *table*. É incluído o nome do produto e quantidade, e por fim apenas o botão de remover o produto da table. Eu tenho um `input hidden` que deveria ser preenchido com um array de todos os produtos adicionados à table deste jeito:

```
value="[nomeproduto][25],[produto2][15]"
```

Cada vez que eu adiciono um produto à table deve ser adicionado ao value deste `input hidden`, mas meu codigo só insere 1 produto, o outro problema é que ao remover o produto também ele deve sair do value do `input hidden`.

O código:

```
$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {
    var table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Tabela de produtos
        list = $('#lista_produtos').val(), // Select com a lista de produtos
        quant = $('#quant_produtos').val(), // Campo com a quantidade de produtos
        remove = "<a href='#' class='del_produto'><i class='icon-remove-small'></i></a>", // Link para remover o produto
        input_hidden = $('#products_array'),
        prod_array = []; // Array de produtos
    // Remove a mensagem de cesta vazia depois que produto é adicionado
    $('#cesta_vazia').remove();
    // Insere o produto selecionado no select list dentro da tabela
    table.append("<tr><td class='produto'>" + list + "</td><td class='quantidade'>" + quant + "</td><td>" + remove + "</td></tr>");
    prod_array.push("[" + list + "]" + "[" + quant + "]");
    input_hidden.val(prod_array);
    console.log("novo produto adicionado :)");
    console.log(input_hidden.val());
});

// Remoção de produtos da tabela
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Janela de confirmação de exclusão do item
    var dialog = confirm("Clique 'OK' para remover o produto, ou 'cancelar' para mantê-lo na lista.");
    if (dialog == true) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        console.log("produto removido :(");
    } else if (dialog == false) {
        console.log("produto mantido :O");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K2hc4/1/

Comment: Pode colocar o seu HTML também? Ideal era fazer um jsFiddle com o problema.

Comment: adicionado à final da pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concordo com a resposta do Sergio, talvez seja melhor reavaliar o maneira de capturar os parâmetros, mais se você deseja manter esta estratégia, segue uma sugestão de implementação

**1º Ao adicionar produtos** - Sempre que há `onclick` para adicionar um novo produtor, você recria o  `prod_array = [];`, desta forma fica sempre o último produto no array, sugiro você definir este array como variável global, exemplo:

```
prod_array = []; // Array de produtos
$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {

    var table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Tabela de produtos  
        list = $('#lista_produtos').val(), // Select com a lista de produtos
        quant = $('#quant_produtos').val(), // Campo com a quantidade de produtos
      remove = "<a href='#' class='del_produto'>Remover<i class='icon-remove-small'></i></a>", 
      // Link para remover o produto
    input_hidden = $('#products_array');

    // Remove a mensagem de cesta vazia depois que produto é adicionado
    $('#cesta_vazia').remove();
    // Insere o produto selecionado no select list dentro da tabela
    table.append("<tr><td class='produto'>" + list + "</td><td class='quantidade'>" + quant + "</td><td>" + remove + "</td></tr>");
    prod_array.push("[" + list + "]" + "[" + quant + "]");
    input_hidden.val(prod_array);
    console.log("novo produto adicionado :)");
    console.log(input_hidden.val());
});
```

**2º Ao remover item** - Para remover o produto do array, você terá que localizá-lo pelo valor e remover, no exemplo abaixo utilizei **[splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)**, para remover o item:

```
   // Remoção de produtos da tabela
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Janela de confirmação de exclusão do item
    var dialog = confirm("Clique 'OK' para remover o produto, ou 'cancelar' para mantê-lo na lista.");

    if (dialog == true) {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); //seleciona a tr
        var list = tr.find('td').eq(0).text(); // seleciona o produto
        var quant = tr.find('td').eq(1).text(); // seleciona a quantidade
        //procura a posição no array
        var index = prod_array.indexOf("[" + list + "]" + "[" + quant + "]");
        prod_array.splice(index, 1); //remove do array
        tr.remove(); //remove a linha
        console.log("produto removido :(");
        console.log(prod_array);

    } else if (dialog == false) {

        console.log("produto mantido :O");
        console.log(prod_array);

    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2hc4/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro mudar de estratégia.

Mantendo a sua ideia de ter uma string, teste fazer assim:

```
function recalcular(item, qtd) {
    prod_array[item] = qtd;
    var string = '';
    for (var prod in prod_array) {
        if (prod_array[prod]) string += '[' + prod + '][' + prod_array[prod] + ']';
    }
    $('#products_array').val(string);
}
```

Esta ideia deve contudo ser usada numa função para a poder chamar do `remover` também. Note que o objeto estar em escopo disponivel.

**Se quiser fazer de uma nova maneira** use esse objeto em cima, retire o input hidden, e faça a submissão via ajax passando `prod_array.serialize()` no campo `data`. Esta maneira facilita também a remoção de elementos quando clicar no remover uma vez que pode fazer `delete prod_array.nomeproduto;` ou somente pôr a zero `prod_array.nomeproduto = 0;`

### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gbKnT/