# Usar splice() para remover um array do value de um input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Peguei o código de um usuário daqui que postou ([adicionar/remover array a um input hidden](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22985/adicionar-remover-array-a-um-input-hidden)), adicionei algumas coisas e até tentei modificar como os usuários que responderam sugeriram, mas não consegui retirar o array do value do produto removido.

```
var strong = $('#total'),
total = 0.00;
prod_array = []; // Array de produtos
$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {

   var table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Tabela de produtos  
   list = $('#lista_produtos').html(), // Select com a lista de produtos
   quant = parseInt($('#mudeValor').val()), // Campo com a quantidade de produtos
   preco = parseFloat($('#preco').val()),

   // Link para remover o produto
   input_hidden = $('#products_array');

   preco = preco * quant;
   preco = parseFloat(preco.toFixed(2));

   // Remove a mensagem de cesta vazia depois que produto é adicionado
   $('#cesta_vazia').remove();
   // Insere o produto selecionado no select list dentro da tabela
   table.append("<tr><td>" + quant + "</td><td>x</td><td>" + list + "</td><td>R$ </td><td>" + preco + "</td><td><a href='#' class='del_produto'><i><strong>X</strong></i></a></td></tr>");
   prod_array.push("[" + quant + "]" + "[" + list + "]");
   input_hidden.val(prod_array);
   console.log("novo produto adicionado :)");
   console.log(input_hidden.val());

   strong = $('#total'),
   total = total + preco;
   total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2));
   $('#totalold').remove();
   strong.append("<strong id='totalold'>" + total + "</strong>");
});

// Remoção de produtos da tabela
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); //seleciona a tr
   var quant = tr.find('td').eq(0).html(); // seleciona a quantidade
   var list = tr.find('td').eq(2).html(); // seleciona o produto

   strong = $('#total'),
   total = total - preco;
   total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2));
   $('#totalold').remove();
   strong.append("<strong id='totalold'>" + total + "</strong>");

   //procura a posição no array
   var index = prod_array.indexOf("[" + quant + "]" + "[" + list + "]");
   prod_array.splice(index, 2);//remove do array
   tr.remove(); //remove a linha
   console.log("produto removido :(");
   console.log(prod_array);

});
```

Comment: coloca um `console.log(index);` no final e veja que valor retorna. Talvez não esteja encontrando a string na array.

Comment: Man, ele reconhece a posição que o array começa, os dois array estão iguais, o problema é no splice(), ele não está removendo.

Comment: Isto é inequívoco: `array = ['red','blue','gray']; index = array.indexOf('blue'); array.splice(index,2);`'. O resultado da array será: `array=['red'];`. Logo, é importante verificar se o`index` está retornando a posição correta em `prod_array.indexOf("[" + quant + "]" + "[" + list + "]");`. É mais coerente pressupor que há algum erro no seu código do que dizer que o `splice` não está funcionando.